# How does one find "suitable referees" for publishing a paper in journal?

Tags: publications, journals

In many journals, authors who have never published anything before are required to have two or more "referees" in order for the paper to be reviewed. Who are these referees, and how can one "find suitable ones"?

Also, how does one go about finding referees when one is not in academia (i.e. doing research as a hobby rather than a profession)?

Comment: Can you please clarify what field you are talking about? In my fields, pretty much no reputable journal *requires* you to supply referees---and in fact, author-suggested referees are often considered less reliable than ones independently identified by the journal.

Comment: Usually you can simply suggest authors of the most important recent references cited in your manuscript as referees. That might not be terribly useful to the editor but is the best way to fulfill this requirement if you don't know anyone in your field. However, I suggest to ask your adviser for suggestions. Helping you with this is their job.

Comment: An example is The Journal of Integer Sequences: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/

Comment: @Pickle The statement on the journal you linked is: "Authors may want to suggest two or three names of possible referees."  In other words, you don't have to: the journal is quite willing and able to find what it thinks are appropriate reviewers for the paper.

Comment: @jakebeal OK. But having referre(s) would certainly help towards the publication of the paper. The question is: how does one fund "suitable" ones?

Comment: You naming several referees does not 'help towards the publication' - it merely gives a hint to the editor of who you think might be good, and what area you think the paper is in. If those names publish in, and are referees for, the journal, the editor has a better idea of what group of potential referees to dig some names out of.

Comment: @JonCuster Aah OK thanks a lot for the precision. I guess I was confused as to the utility of a "referee"

Comment: You need to think of the scale of a journal - suppose an issue consisting of ~30 articles comes out once a month. They accept about 25% of all submissions. That means the editorial team has to process about 4 submissions _a day_, figuring out who would make a good referee. And then you need to come up with more than the minimum number of names to find people with the time real soon now to do it. Most journals also have some breadth in their topics, so an editor may not have intimate knowledge of the current state of some sub-field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, most journals do not *require* you to propose referees. It's more like the journal *allows you* to propose some names of potential referees. The referees are appointed by the editor and you as author will not know their names.

So the answer to "How does one go about finding referees when one is not in academia?" is

**You don't have to.**

Just find a suitable journal that does not require that you suggest referees.

If the journal management system does not allow you to submit your paper without suggesting referees, either suggest authors that you cite or authors that cite the same papers you cite (using, e.g., Google scholar).

Comment: I've submitted to journals where the submission system required recommendation of referees. Your last sentence is wrong.

Comment: @Roland Not if you choose the right journals :-).

Comment: Whether I need to suggest reviewers is usually not my most important concern when selecting a journal. I know (of) enough scientists in my research area.

Comment: @Roland I updated the answer in view of your comment.

Comment: I think it depends on the field (and potentially its breadth?). My field (geography) is very broad, and though I haven't submitted many articles,  my understanding is that it is very common (often required) to suggest referees.

Answer (score 0):

Typically look at the highest ranking people which you cited.

- Highest ranking: since the journal will like that they dont need your citations
- People which you cited: most likely they cas easier get into the topic, since they may know the foundations.

Comment: What if the highest ranking people cited have retired/died/no longer active? What if none of the citees are available?

Comment: Ok. That is a problem - then look who cited these people the most.